# Can the firebase emulator be used as a local server like “Live Server” for example?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have been using the Firebase Emulator as a local server for development purposes. I have noticed an issue, however. When I make CSS changes, the updates are only reflected for some time but then any subsequent CSS changes are not shown. It seems to be that it does not exactly operate as a local server like “Live Server”, “Live Preview” and other similar servers used for previewing changes on the browser. It stops showing the changes at some point. I can not figure out why this is happening. Any clue?

I tried to disable cache in the Network section of the Chrome DevTools but it does not work. If that’s even the problem.

Comment: This sounds like you need a hard reset the site via CTRL+F5 to force reload assets